# How to bypass the library that is not supported on certain iOS versions?

Tags: iphone, ios, version, device

I have a project that require AlAssetsLibrary as well as UIImagePickerViewController. I have created one use ALAssetsLibrary for IOS 4+ but want to use UImagePickerViewController for earlier IOS.

Since some of the code have imported the ALAssetsLibrary within the project and have created an instance variable of the ALAsset object on my custom class. Is there a way of hiding those variables and the import statement within the code when shifting different device with different IOS version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use "weak linking" to solve this problem.

Here's a guide for turning on weak linking: http://www.vellios.com/2010/07/04/using-ios-4-frameworks-on-os-3/

Comment: Does that mean if I have a variable ALAsset object . The old iOS will ignore it.